# What type of simulation should I use (bootstrap)?

Tags: simulation, statistics-bootstrap

I am new to resampling/simulation, and want to make sure I am using the correct technique. I have real data (small sample sizes n~20) and am trying to compare the [1] error associated with conducting visual counts of an organism (x) to [2] the error associated with using a proxy/indicator (y) to model/predict the count of the organism (x). I wish to extrapolate the sampling beyond my 20 sites (to ~100 sites). Is bootstrap sampling appropriate for this? If so, should it be done with or without replacement? If not, what other method(s) would be appropriate? Thanks